Not booting after converting Virtualbox disk to Hyper-V
I have a RHEL 8 VM image that I have converted from Virtual Box to Hyper-V but it fails to start (works in VB but not in Hyper-V).
Timed out waiting for device dev-di...97\x2d9636\x2dc104a96af2a5.device
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/e563c7aa-66f5-4e26-82e2-4251e99edc91 does not exist
From a little searching I see this may be from the UUID changing.
I followed a few previous answers and ran blkid and looked in /etc/fstab but both of these have a different uuid and match each other.
I don't know much about Linux but how do I fix this? I assume I need to change that device ID above to the one in blkid somewhere but how and where?

Does this help?  You need to alter all the UUID's by creating your own in Hyper-V and then edit every entry in /etc/fstab to match the new ones you created.  If you nees help I'll write an answer but it will take awhile.  Remember to keep your VirtualBox VM as a backup because you'll have all different UUD's in both VM's now.

Thanks @eyoung100, how do I create my own UUID in Hyper-V?

Read the reply in the link I posted. The process is similar in Hyper-V if not the procedure outlined.

I tried to follow the instructions in the answer, but I can't find any "modify" option when I edit disk. I only have options to compact, convert and expand. What am I missing?

You don't have the rights?

Also, make sure the machine isn't running while trying to modify it.  That's kind of a given I know, but just in case...

I apologize, the options have been updated since that post.  Hyper-V version changes have changed the option wording  since that post.  See my answer below for High Level steps.  If you need details, let me know here and I'll provide commands etc, but that will take awhile.

Changing fstab alone is not enough. You need to rebuild the GRUB config as well.

Converting From Virtualbox to Hyper-V
The High Level Process is as follows:

Export the VM from VirtualBox into a compatible format that Hyper-V can convert, most likely VHD.
Convert the Disk from Step 1 into the Native Hyper-V format, VHD ==> VHDX.
Create a Hyper-V instance with no disk attached.
Attach the Converted Disk from Step 2 onto the Machine in Step 3.
Modify the Boot options and reboot the Hyper-V instance that was created.

Added Steps (High Level) In the OP's case we need to add:

After Booting, we now need to test for errors.
If the error described RE: Timeouts still occurs in the converted disk, we need to "attach" a LiveDistro ISO to the CD Controller, boot into the live distro, mount the RHEL disk, create new UUID's using the LiveDisks command prompt, and modify the /etc/fstab file of the mounted RHEL disk to match the new UUID's we created.


I did try and do this but I wasn't sure how to mount the drive. I will try again and report back with a conclusion when I have some more time to spend this. Thank you for all of your help so far.

@johna You're Welcome
